# How to process Jsonb in KSQL?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

In  KSQLdb i need to process JSONB from PostgreSQL, but i don't see any information on JSONB with KSQLdb.
I can see the value format field as JSON but how can we access JSONB in that.

Comment: Why not write your own deserailizer?

Answer (score 1):

ksqlDB doesn't support JSONB at the moment (February 2020).

You can raise an enhancement request here: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/new

Comment: Can't we do it using UDF ? One of the field inside the table is JSONB.